# Dropzonejs complete delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I use Dropzonejs, but I want to run following commands, but there is no delay with upload the files via dropzonejs.

```
            myDropzone.processQueue();
            AS.Util.displaySuccessMessage($('#begin'), response.message);
            $('html,body').scrollTop(0);
            setTimeout(
                function()
                {
                    window.location.assign("entryview?id=" + response.insert)
                }, 2500);
```

How can I run the command under the processQueue, after completing uploading?

Comment: [Have you read the docs?](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#events) The `success` or `complete` (or their `multiple` versions) events are fired when file(s) are finished uploading, maybe that's the place to put your code?